# Save word file with VBA userform and macro

Tags: vba, ms-word

I created a VBA userform with some functions and running it with a macro and saved it as a .docm file. But the problem is when I am trying to run that docm file from another computer, nothing is working. And later when I checked the VBA code, I saw my userForm1 was not there. I have no idea what is going on there. How to solve this issue, so that I can run my VBA form into another computer ?

Comment: Though I got a solution. But I dont think this is ultimate one. Solution is load those forms and macro into a dotm file by clicking Macros Menu>Organizer>Transfers all forms and macros into that dotm file >save the dotm file. And when you need to restore it into another computer, just reverse the process and store those into the Normal.dotm file.

Comment: Excuse me to be a little bit rude, but have you ever bothered to read some documentation about how to work with macros in Word? Macros and user forms can be saved in any macro-enabled template file (dotm) and ships with it. Please google for some more information or walkthrough for the basics; e.g. http://word.mvps.org/FAQs/MacrosVBA/index.htm is a good starting point, or the MSDN pagees for Office VBA development.

Comment: Have you checked the macro security settings on the "other" computer?

Comment: Yeah its working now. Problem was to set it as autoexec. But problem is solved now. Please see my first comment for the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I got a solution. But I dont think this is ultimate one. Solution is load those forms and macro into a dotm file by clicking Macros Menu>Organizer>Transfers all forms and macros into that dotm file >save the dotm file. And when you need to restore it into another computer, just reverse the process and store those into the Normal.dotm file.